# Getting the product.id in my django slug product details

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, templates

I'm having issues trying to get my product.id in my product_details templates.

This is my views.py product_details

```
def product_details(request, slug):
    data = cartData(request)
    cartItems = data['cartItems']

    post = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug)
   
    context = {
        'post': post,
        'cartItems': cartItems,
    }      
    return render(request, 'e_commerce/product_details.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_image', null=True, blank=True)
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=1)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='', null=True, blank=True)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, help_text='Input size of product')
```

urls.py

```
 path('<slug:slug>/', views.product_details, name='product_details'),#e_commerce details page
```

Then the product_details template:

```
<div class="container">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="container-fliud">
                        <div class="wrapper row">
                            <div class="preview col-md-6">
                                <div class="preview-pic tab-content">
                                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="pic-1"><img src="{{ post.image.url }}" /></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="details col-md-6">
                                <h3 class="product-title">{% block title %} {{ post.name }} {% endblock title %}</h3>
                                <div class="rating">
                                    <div class="stars">

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <h5 class="product-description">{{post.description }}</h5>
                                <h4 class="price">price: <span>NGN {{ post.price }}</span></h4>
                                <h5 class="sizes">size: {{ post.size }}</h5>
                                <h5 class="lead">Category: {{ post.category }}</h5>
                                <hr>
                                  <button data-product=**{{product.id}}**  data-action="add" class="btn btn-outline-secondary add-btn update-cart">Add to Cart</button>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Everything is working out fine and good except getting the product.id.

I need it in order to consume the javascript function I created to enable the users to add to cart by clicking the **'Add to cart'** button in the templates.

Comment: I dont see you passing a 'product' in your views context. You're passing only 'post' and 'cartItems'

Comment: I queried the Product model with  `post = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug)` @d1spstack, i guess that;s why i'm passing it to my views context.

Comment: But youre context doest have a variable called 'product'. Youre storing the query in a variable called 'post' and then trying to access the query in the template via a variable called 'product'.

Comment: @d1spstack yeah i later realized that. I've worked on it, instead of product, i used post. thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I later came up with a solution to my issue.

I only needed to include `{{ post.id }}` to get my `product.id`.

Comment: Maybe next time you might want to name your product object `product`, not `post`...

Comment: @AKX sure. i will take that to mind. Thanks